# C# not breaking loop for no reason

Tags: c#, vhosts

I'm writing some code that parses an Apache config file.

The File im parsing:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the parser method filePath is the path to the above file.

```
public void readFile(string filePath)
    {
        /* read the file path provided */
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        /* remove the comments from the file */
        string[] lines = content.Split('\n');
        string newContent = "";
        foreach(string line in lines){
            char[] chars = line.ToCharArray();
            if(chars[0] != '#'){
                newContent += line+"\n";
            }
        }

        /* search for Virtual hosts and save them */
        string regEx = "<VirtualHost [^>]*>[^<]*</VirtualHost>";
        MatchCollection coll = Regex.Matches(newContent, regEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string[] vhosts = new string[coll.Count];
        int counter = 0;

        /* go though them and save them into a string array */
        foreach (Match match in coll)
        {
            vhosts[counter] = (match.Value);
            counter++;
        }

        /* set the number of vhosts */
        hosts = new vhost[vhosts.Count()];

        /* go though the string array */
        for (int c = 0; c < vhosts.Count(); c++ )
        {

            MessageBox.Show("hi");

            /* set the host string to current vhost string */
            string host = vhosts[c];
            /* get the lines from the vhost */
            string[] lines2 = host.Split('\n');
            /* create the new save object in the array of vhosts */
            hosts[c] = new vhost();
            /* tell the console what were proccessing */
            Console.WriteLine((c+1).ToString() + " of " + vhosts.Count().ToString());
            /* for each line add the rule to the correct vHost via the counter for looping though the vhosts */
            for (int i = 0; i < lines2.Count(); i++)
            {
                /* set the string line to the line were currently on */
                string line = lines2[i];
                /* get rid of whitespace and split on the space (' ')*/
                string[] param = line.Trim().Split(' ');
                /* provde the current vHost number and the key and value in the config file */
                hosts[c].addRule(param[0], param[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

`hosts` is a `vHost[]` vHost is as below

```
class vhost
{
    public vhostRules[] rules = new vhostRules[1];

    public string getRuleValue(string key)
    {
        vhostRules[] currentRules = rules;
        rules = new vhostRules[currentRules.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRules.Count(); i++)
        {
            vhostRules Rule = currentRules[i];
            if (key == Rule.key)
                return Rule.value;
        }
        return "";
    }

    public vhostRules getRule(string key)
    {
        vhostRules[] currentRules = rules;
        rules = new vhostRules[currentRules.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRules.Count(); i++)
        {
            vhostRules Rule = currentRules[i];
            if (key == Rule.key)
                return Rule;
        }
        return new vhostRules();
    }

    public vhostRules[] getRules()
    {
        return rules;
    }

    public void addRule(string key, string rule)
    {
        vhostRules[] currentRules = rules;
        rules = new vhostRules[currentRules.Count()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRules.Count(); i++)
        {
            vhostRules Rule = currentRules[i];
            rules[i] = Rule;
            counter++;
        }
        rules[counter] = new vhostRules();
        rules[counter].key = key;
        rules[counter].value = rule;
    }

    public void removeRule(string key)
    {
        vhostRules[] currentRules = rules;
        rules = new vhostRules[currentRules.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRules.Count(); i++)
        {
            vhostRules Rule = currentRules[i];
            if (key != Rule.key)
                rules[i] = Rule;
        }
    }

    public void changeRule(string key, string value)
    {
        vhostRules[] currentRules = rules;
        rules = new vhostRules[currentRules.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRules.Count(); i++)
        {
            vhostRules Rule = currentRules[i];
            if (key != Rule.key)
            {
                rules[i] = Rule;
                rules[i].value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The vhostRules Object

`class vhostRules { public string key; public string value; }`

and `vhostRules` is basicly a class to save key and value

Now the problem is `hosts[c].addRule(param[0], param[1]);` of the read file above as you can see its is calling `addRule` as above again inside class `vhost` even if i empty addRule so there is no code inside this still does not work.

This is the only way i can show the problem there is no smaller way to replicate as the error appears to be with the compiled end result

The only way i have found is the comment or remove the `hosts[c].addRule(param[0], param[1]);` from my code then it works but as above when i empty it, it does not work that is theoretically incorrect

Stepping though the code does as its does no error occurs and it only runs the loop once,

NO ERRORS OCCUR THIS INCLUDES NO SILENT DEATH NO EXCEPTIONS AND NO FREEZING/CRASHING

**update**
Updated reader

```
try
{
    hosts[c].addRule(param[0], param[1]);
}catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
```

Provides output

```
1 of 2
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
2 of 2
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
Index was outside the bounds of the array
```

The Break point info

```
param = {string[2]} 
    [0] = "ServerAdmin" 
    [1] = "webmaste
```

r@dummy-host.example.com"

Comment: "there is no problem with the code other than it does not run". Boy, I think that's the problem with most code that doesn't run!

Comment: It was a fair comment: "There's nothing wrong with my car, the engine just won't start".

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend posting the relevant parts of your code... I'm not waiting 45 seconds to download something from MegaUpload to have to pick through to be able to begin helping you with your code that has no problems.

Comment: Idealy yes but if he had read what i posted he would have understud what i was referencing to i have 2 programmers look at this and tell me theoretical its correct just in compilation is it wrong

Comment: Do you know how big that would be i have 3 classes just for saving data correctly. ppl would hate me for that much reading when they can follow the code in VS better than me trying to explain

Comment: So show us the `relevant` sections, it can't be the whole thing that's not working. Try to reproduce it in as small an example as possible and post that.

Comment: @Barkermn01: if your application is that big, then no one will look all through it. Try to produce a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. In the process of doing that you might just as well find out what the problem is.

Comment: I would hate you more if I had to download something from MegaUpload, extract it, open it in VS (possibly having to convert it to the correct version beforehand), and then get it to run resolving any reference issues the code may have, and only then be able to debug it. That's assuming I've got VS available to me right now...

Comment: Well its VS2010 and get it running even if your on linux and use Mono it works if your using VS why would it not work. on another note if you are not aware there are only 2 compilers for C# one is VS the other is mono both would support a VS project so you can see the code if you would have to install VS you dont work in C# as you require one of the 2 to work with c#

Comment: There are certain key values in your code that you should check. For example, what is the value of vhosts.Count()?  How big does counter get?  What is the value of coll.Count?   These variables control most of the loop, and should be checked carefully.  

Then you should describe exactly how the program "breaks".  Is there a seg-fault? unhandled exception? silent death? simply does something other than expected?  You have not provided basic info in this question.

Comment: @Barlermn01: the base problem remains: if you restrict the number of people who want to help you to those who are willing to download/compile/run your code, then you might not get a lot of help.

Comment: abelenky - stop there if you dont know you should not be working with C# a count is the count of the array its size is when ever it is for parsing the file if you dont know that dont work in c#

Comment: @Joachim Sauer i just cant win, if i only posted the readFile you would ask what a vHost object is and then ask what a vHostRules object is and i would have to explain but if i post it you still say its to much i cant shrink it as i dont understand the problem so i dont know what can create it

Comment: @Barkermn01: it's not about winning or losing. It's about solving problems. If you make it easy for us to help you, you'll get lots of help. If you don't make it easy, then you won't get lots of help. It's as simple as that. And reducing the problem until every further reduction makes the problem go away (i.e. producing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) not only helps us help you, it may also help you fix the problem on your own.

Comment: @Barkermn01 grate use of terminology them me change then if i post it all ppl have ago if i only posted part of it using other parts would cause ppl to have ago saying i have not given them the info so i though it would be easier for my to tell them the problem and provide them with the code that way easier to work with apparently ppl just like to have ago no matter what though for there ease was used

Comment: I'm sorry, it's really hard to follow what you're saying. Please use *some* punctuation and preferably use whole, correct words.

Comment: If, as you say, "NO ERRORS OCCUR THIS INCLUDES NO SILENT DEATH NO EXCEPTIONS AND NO FREEZING/CRASHING", then what exactly is the problem?  That sounds like a working program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to provide an actual answer on this:

My initial guess - and it is only a guess, as we don't have all the information we need - is that there is an exception being thrown somewhere within the loop.

The most likely candidate I can see for the exception is the line:

```
hosts[c].addRule(param[0], param[1]);
```

The addRule method within the `vhost` class does some pretty funky stuff, but again, we don't have all the info, so I can't say for sure.

**What we need**

We will at least need to know what is happening. Is an exception being thrown? What line does it get up to? Does it silently die? Have you stepped through the code?

Please, help us to help you...

**Update**
So, the issue is somewhere in:

```
string[] param = line.Trim().Split(' ');                
hosts[c].addRule(param[0], param[1]);
```

OR:

```
public void addRule(string key, string rule)
    {
        vhostRules[] currentRules = rules;
        rules = new vhostRules[currentRules.Count()];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRules.Count(); i++)
        {
            vhostRules Rule = currentRules[i];
            rules[i] = Rule;
            counter++;
        }
        rules[counter] = new vhostRules();
        rules[counter].key = key;
        rules[counter].value = rule;
    }
```

OR:

Within the constructor of `vhostRules`, as shown by the line:

```
rules[counter] = new vhostRules();
```

Now, what is the key you are using for the key value pair within `rules[]`?

**You could try**
Changing the line:

```
string[] param = line.Trim().Split(' ');
```

to:

```
string[] param = line.Trim().Split(new char[] {' '}, 2);
```

This will allow you to keep the `common` at the end of some of your lines... This is probably not causing your main issue, but it's likely to be **an** issue at least.

**Update 2**
Set a breakpoint after the line above (`string[] param = line.Trim().Split(new char[] {' '}, 2);`, and see what param is actually set to. Add a watch, see *exactly* what param[0] and param[1] are. I have a feeling they're OK, and it's actually somewhere **within** the addRule method that the exception is being thrown...

So again, add error handling around the code within the addRule method, and see what is being output. Look at the stack trace, check the line numbers, and show us exactly what is going on in there.

Comment: any unhandled Exception is thrown into the debugger as you can see there is no error handling so all are unhandled

Comment: Firstly, you've still not answered anything that's in the **What we need** section. Secondly, not necessarily: check Debug menu in VS, Options and Settings. Ensure "Enable the exception assistant" and all other relevant options are enabled.

Comment: mate go read i said "i stepped though the code it does the problem" i told you it does not error and told you there is no exceptions thrown yes my VS is setup correctly to handle exceptions so this is the point your having ago at me when this is what im confirming why i gave a download for the code was so that you could see this

Comment: Sure, that is what you said, I'm not disputing that. So, you have an issue in the addRule method by the looks of things. Which leads us to needing to see constructor for `vhostRules`, as called by `new vhostRules();`. You mention that removing all code from the addRule method leaves the same result, which leads me to believe the rules are not being added to the collection correctly. What are you using as the Key for the collection? Is this being duplicated somewhere?

Comment: `class vhostRules
    {
        public string key;
        public string value;
    }`

Its just that no construct or any thing

Comment: Your update is wrong as said
"if i empty addRule so there is no code inside this still does not work."

So even if i have `public void addRule(string key, string rule)
    {}`
It still does not work but then if i comment the call to addRule it works

Comment: So you get rid of the call to addRule, and "Hi" outputs twice? Which means that you have the right number of elements in `vhosts`, but somewhere in addRule the loop is being terminated. Humor us, as a test, put the whole block of code in a try/catch block, and see what output you can get from `catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}`

Comment: Well done Guys i'm getting "the Index was outside of the bound of the array" how ever why this is being handled with no handling in place is a flaming miracle

Comment: Not a miracle, just an example of why proper exception handling is always helpful - don't rely solely on your debugger to tell you there is an exception.

Comment: Yea apart from that exception is firing wrongly now look at my update section

Comment: It is not "firing wrongly", it is firing exactly as it always has and always will do with that code. Check my update and add the suggested exception handling. It must be erroring again within the addRule method.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution to your problem, but at least some cleanup: change this line:

```
public vhostRules[] rules = new vhostRules[1];
```

into

```
private List<vhostRules> rules = new List<vhostRules>();
```

then you don't need to recopy that array every time you need to add an item, just `.Add()` it.

You might then change

```
public vhostRules[] getRules()
{
    return rules;
}
```

into

```
using System.Linq;
public vhostRules[] getRules()
{
    return rules.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm going to +1 this, just because I've been so tempted to say many similar things about tidying up the code whilst looking at it. @Barkermn01 - take note, refactor as much of this code as possible, and you, and I, will have a **much** easier time of debugging.

Comment: Mate your gonna love this but this fixed the final bug for me so thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. You execute this code for each line in each virtual host definition:

```
/* get rid of whitespace and split on the space (' ')*/
string[] param = line.Trim().Split(' ');
/* provde the current vHost number and the key and value in the config file */
hosts[c].addRule(param[0], param[1]);
```

This assumes that every line contains at least 2 space-separated values. That's true for all of them **except** for the last one: `</VirtualHost>`.

I'd expect you to get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (or whatever that is called in .NET), but something seems to swallow that.

Comment: Just saw the same thing :) I've just asked him to wrap the whole thing in a try/catch block to see if we can get some exception output. Unless it's being swallowed further down the stack, we should actually get something to go on.

Comment: Well done Guys i'm getting "the Index was outside of the bound of the array" how ever why this is being handled with no handling in place is a flaming miracle